# JAVA: Convert HTML Code to image in transparent

Tags: java, html, image, png, transparent

How can I convert a HTML code into a PNG image which is transparent?

```
String s = "<font size="6">Schriftgröße 6</font>"
```

Convert into **transparent** image? How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by convert HTML code to a transparent PNG image? Have an image of the code?

Comment: Yes, I would like to convert the String (my HTML code) to an image file. So it´s moreless the image of the code.

Comment: You can start with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800717/convert-text-content-to-image/18800845#18800845)

Comment: Ok, but than I will get the real code from HTML? I would like the code in HTML translation, but I guess I will get in this code only <font size="6">Schriftgröße 6</font>

Comment: It´s something like this Lib: https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/downloads/detail?name=html2image-0.9.jar&can=2&q= But I cannot convert it to transparent image in this lib?

Comment: @internet The problem with you linked example is it's using a `JEditorPane` as the primary rendering surface, nice idea.  I'm not sure if it would be possible to make a `JEditorPane` which was transparent

Comment: @internet You might also consider having a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796558/javafx-2-0-webview-webengine-render-web-page-to-an-image) example, which makes use of JavaFX's `WebView` which has a much greater support for HTML and CSS then Swing ... But I doubt you'd get it transparent though :P

Comment: I only need html, no CSS code...

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is, the means by which a html text is renderer is buried WAY deep down in the core API.  Been to lazy to go around trying to dig it out, I'd cheat and simply use a `JLabel`, for example...

[image: Example]

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><font size=\"6\">Schriftgröße 6</font></html>");
label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(label.getPreferredSize().width, label.getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
label.printAll(g2d);
g2d.dispose();
try {
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("Text.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you'd like to use the [html2image](https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/downloads/detail?name=html2image-0.9.jar&can=2&q=) API, you'll need to change the way in which the rendering surface it uses is generated.

The API basically uses a `JEditorPane`, which is actually a nice trick, the problem is, you need to make it transparent, maybe something like...

```
HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator() {
    protected JEditorPane createJEditorPane() {
        JEditorPane editor = super.createJEditorPane();
        editor.setOpaque(false);
        return editor;
    }

};
imageGenerator.loadHtml("<font size=\"6\">Schriftgröße 6</font>");
imageGenerator.saveAsImage("hello-world.png");
```

Which outputs...

[image: hello-world.png]