# How can I generate an Image from SVG image with a javafx WebView

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I have an svg file, and I would like to create an Image from it for use on a Canvas.

The following example, creates a WebView gets the corresponding WebEngine and loads the svg content. Then a snapshot is used to create an image.

[image: example program display]

The correct display should not have the white rectangle because that region of the ellipse image should be transparent.  This has two main issues:

1. The resulting Image has an opaque background.
2. I need to display a Stage containing the WebView for the graphics to be drawn.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;

import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotResult;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class SvgWebView extends Application{
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(512, 512);
    AnimationTimer loader; 

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        loadGraphics();
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(canvas);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Svg from webview");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 640);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    Void setImage(SnapshotResult result){
        Image img = result.getImage();
        GraphicsContext g2d = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        g2d.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 512);
        g2d.drawImage(img, 192, 129);
        loader.stop();
        return null;
    }
    public void loadGraphics(){
        WebView view = new WebView();
        Scene sprites = new Scene(view, 128, 128);
        WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
        String content = "<svg width=\"128px\" height=\"128px\" viewBox=\"0 0 128 129\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\">" +
                         "<ellipse cx=\"64px\" cy=\"64px\" rx=\"64px\" ry=\"32px\" stroke=\"#f00\" fill=\"#00f\"/></svg>";
        engine.loadContent(content, "image/svg+xml");
        engine.reload();
        Stage s = new Stage( ); //necessary to create image.
        s.setScene(sprites);
        s.show();
        loader = new AnimationTimer(){
            long count = 0;
            public void handle(long now){
                if( count++ == 2 ){
                    //work around from linked question
                    SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
                    params.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    view.snapshot( rlt->setImage(rlt), params, null);
                    loader.stop();
                    s.hide();
                }

            }
        };
        loader.start();

    }

}
```

This question is similar to [SVG Image in JavaFX 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436274/svg-image-in-javafx-2-2) but it is more specific, in that I am actually looking at one of the solutions proposed.

The animation timer is used as per this question [JavaFX 2.0+ WebView /WebEngine render web page to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796558/javafx-2-0-webview-webengine-render-web-page-to-an-image/13688899#comment109572864_13688899) and it does appear to be necessary.

tested on OSX with 'openjdk version "11.0.6"' using both javafx 11.0.2 and 14.0.1